# i need YA Woocommerce Countdown Slider in Visual Composer

Tags: woocommerce, slider, countdown

i am making template like "himarket" (http://wpthemego.com/premium-themes-on-themeforest/himarket.html)
i need that plugin (YA Woocommerce Countdown Slider) in Visual Composer.
like this:
[in visual composer pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW3uL.png)
how can i add make it ino my visual composer.
what is (YA Woocommerce Countdown Slider) download link?
and how i add it into visual composer?
tnx for response.

Comment: tnx for your response....do you know what is that plugin name?

Comment: I really don't know … You should better ask in visual composer support threads. StackOverFlow is a coding forum so we care about coding. Plugin or tutorial recommendations are just of-topic here.